# How to fix "error: no source files" in Flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio, pubspec

Everything was working fine but After I upgrade my Android studio I started getting the error below when I run `flutter run`:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> error: no source files
```

**Flutter doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 10.16 20A4300b darwin-x64, locale
    fr-BF)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  firebase_analytics: ^6.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
  firebase_core_web: ^0.2.0
  cloud_firestore_web: ^0.2.0+1
  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: ^2.0.1
```

How can I just fix this please?

Comment: Did you success `pub get`?

Comment: yes, I even clear the projet before